# SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter does not work

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I want to add a note about necessary authentification for calling WebAPI and try to do it:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Title = "Tablet Management",
                Version = "v1",
                Contact = new Contact
                {
                    Name = "Oleg Shastitko",
                    Email = "oshastitko@3mdsolutions.com"
                },
            });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new ApiKeyScheme
            {
                Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"bearer {token}\"",
                In = "header",
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = "apiKey"
            });
            c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
```

but I get an error:

> Fetch error undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json

if I remove this line:

```
        //c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
```

it works, but without what I want. How to fix it?

Comment: Which version of swashbuckle are you using?

Comment: I use 4.0.1 version

Answer (score 3):

Add Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters to your project through Nuget Package Manager.